# Notepad++ Regular expression, select a range of characters except a string sequence

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to select a range of characters except this sequence ", (the double quotes and the comma)
How could i group them as single char after ^
when using this [^",] it select all the characters except " and , not the sequence ",

**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
(?:[^"]+("[^,])?)*
```

Comment: Thank You,
I used this from what you wrote : [^"]+("[^,])